# android, How to set left padding of Radiobutton's button programmatically?

Tags: android, radio-button, padding

I use

```
appMusicTab.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.all);
```

to set the RadioButton's button style,

But the drawable is always algin to the left of RadioGroup, How can I set a left padding to the 'button' in Code? Thanks!!

I've tried

```
appMusicTab.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
```

And:

```
  appMusicTab.setLeft(20);
```

But those do not worked.

This is my code:

```
       RadioButton appMusicTab = new RadioButton(mContext);

        appMusicTab.setText(tabInfo.name);
        appMusicTab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);
        appMusicTab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        appMusicTab.setId(tabInfo.id);
//        appMusicTab.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
        appMusicTab.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.all);

        appMusicTab.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_tab_bg);
        appMusicTab.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams lp =
            new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                    RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.bottomMargin =MASettings.MAIN_UI_APP_TAB_MARGIN_BOTTOM;


        mAppsTab.addView(appMusicTab, lp); //mAppsTab is a RadioGroup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a icon with some transparent paddings to solve this problem. I checked RadioButton source code and found that the left padding of button Drawable has been set to 0 in code: buttonDrawable.setBounds(0, y, buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), y + height);

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to set the LayoutParams.

See below:

```
qButt = new Button(this);
qButt.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(BtnHeight,BtnHeight); // You can set any Layout params in Place of TableRow
YourParentLayout.addView(qButt,params); // Your parent layout may be any Layout in xml
```

Comment: Here i have add Button instead of the RadioButton. You can do same thing with RadioButton.

Comment: Thanks IDroid, but the setPadding() seems not working here. I've update my code in the question.

Comment: I found setPadding has effect on text in it, not the button in the radiobutton.

Comment: try FILL_PARENT  or WRAP_CONTENT instead of the MATCH_PARENT in above code and let me tell what happend ?

Comment: I used a icon with some transparent paddings to solve this problem. I checked RadioButton source code and found that the left padding of button Drawable has been set to 0 in code: buttonDrawable.setBounds(0, y, buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), y + height);